# ProgressBar Xamarin Forms not updating

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, progress-bar

I Have a Progress Bar in my code and is used to wait a long download image.

```
var  progress = new ProgressBar()
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
};
progress.Progress = 00;
```

In my saveImage method I have a callback that is implemented like this:`

```
private async void FileService_ImageSuccess(string url, string path)
{
    double step = (double)count / 100;
    await progress.ProgressTo(step, 800, Easing.Linear);
    count++;
}
```

But my progress Bar not refreshing the status, I debug my code and step values is correct, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you executing on the UI thread?  You can use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() to force this

Comment: what is the action parameter, in this method?

Comment: that is the code you want to execute on the UI thread, typically: () => { // UI code goes here }

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. But can you try this code:

```
private async void FileService_ImageSuccess(string url, string path)
{
    double step = (double)count / 100;
    await progress.ProgressTo(step, 800, Easing.Linear);
    count++;
    await Task.Yield();
}
```